# Do either of these plot points in Batman v Superman have a precedents in comics?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

So, *Batman v Superman* left me... jaded. Beyond the film’s other failings, there were two points I found rather hard to swallow. They both stem from the same thing, so I'm wondering if they have a comic-based precedent, or if it's just something WB pulled out of their marketing department to shoe-horn as many cameos in as possible.

The first is

> during Batman's dream sequence, Batman appears to be leading a resistance against a Superman cult. This really isn't out of tone with the movie, as it frames a possible religion being built around the man. Unfortunately, the para-demon like background goons and the **Ω** symbol burned into the ground hint at Darkseid being a player in this dream sequence. Last I checked, Bruce Wayne wasn't also Paul Maud'dib. Have there been any comic examples of him having prescient dreams before?

The second is

> shortly after this dream sequence, we go to *another* dream sequence in which the Flash appears before Bruce Wayne in a time-rift-looking thing to give Bruce vital plot-pertinent information. This in and of itself is nothing new, but it ALSO appears in a dream sequence. Again, this points to Bruce Wayne being able to dream of things he has never encountered before, unless the Flash has a new power to invade someone's dreams.

Comment: I'd go as far as Bruce (and we) maybe just thinking the outer dream level was a dream, while Flash actually was there for real.

Comment: I don't think the first "dream" was actually a dream. My theory is that it was a momentary glimpse into an alternate future, given to Batman as some kind of artifact preceding Flash's time portal. And Zack Snyder has confirmed that the Flash scene was really happening, and that we may see more of that alternate future in the Justice League films.

Comment: Not to my knowledge... Until last, oh, fifth of the movie, I genuinely thought they were getting this set up for an onscreen version of the Injustice storyline. Now, less so. I really think they added that Flash from the future (HEYO) to give them the option to reboot with the Flashpoint storyline, not unlike what was done with Days of Future Past... And alas, as much as I wish they did, the Flash from BvS was not the Flash from the WB.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123064/was-the-messenger-in-bruce-waynes-weird-dream-supposed-to-be-the-flash

Comment: Isn't it an assumption that Batman is the one providing these dream sequences/future glimpses? I don't remember seeing anything indicating he has those abilities, and if you didn't either, maybe it's not him that is the source for these visions?

Comment: I initially downvoted this for the baseless assumption that Bruce was somehow responsible for the visions, but decided to let it go.

Comment: It doesn't seem unreasonable to me to assume that these visions come from Bruce's mind, since throughout the movie we see him have other dreams which are directly derived from his personal memories.

Comment: Not a batman thing but the first reminds me of Alex Ross' Justice and second reminds me of Crisis on Infinite Earths.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is, no I haven't found anything to suggest Bruce Wayne / Batman has ever had any premonition or psychic ability.

To the second question: [Jay Oliva](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0646515/) no stranger to DC universe and a storyboard artist for B v S, says these are future memories caused by a "Time Boom" from Barry's travel through time.

> "You want to know the answer? Okay... you've watched The Flashpoint Paradox, my movie, right? In the DC Universe in the comics, there's this thing where-- it's a little different than the Back to The Future thing where you can go back in time and change your threads and stuff, but in DC, when you go back in time you create this kind of 'Time Boom' kind of thing where lots of things change.
>
> "Okay, so let me just tell you this. Again... I don't know if this is Zack's thinking, but this is mine: what if that isn't a dream sequence? What if what you saw was a Time Boom, a latent memory from the future when Flash comes back? **If you look at the cut, he doesn't go to sleep!** He's waiting for the [Lexcorp file decryption] and suddenly this [Knightmare sequence] comes in, and he's jogged out of it seeing his own death. And what does he see? He sees Flash. And if you're a DC fan, you know what's happening. You know that Flash going back in time, that memory is now coming back to him... mind you, it's jumbled." - [screenrant](https://screenrant.com/batman-v-superman-knightmare-not-dream/)