# In BvS, did Flash show Batman a possible future or just his nightmares come true?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

The scene in **[BvS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_v_Superman%3A_Dawn_of_Justice)** where Batman sees future Flash has prompted a lot of debate online, but there's a question I haven't seen addressed yet. The "nightmare" that Batman had of a Superman gone bad would seem to be the fruition of all his concerns regarding the Kryptonian. Assuming that Flash caused the nightmare, it begs the question of whether that was an actual glimpse into the future (presumably the one that THAT Flash came from)... or if it was a just a nightmare Flash used to get his attention for the message he gave. I know there are lot of extra scenes in the Ultimate Edition cut, but I haven't seen that cut yet.

**Has Zack Snyder or anyone involved with the production of "Batman vs. Superman" commented on whether this was an actual glimpse into a possible future?**

Comment: We don't have any official confirmation of this yet, as far as I can see. Darkseid and Flash are both obviously involved, but that's about it.

Comment: @Allball103 - if that's the correct answer, I'll accept it. I was just hoping that someone had said something while promoting "Justice League".

Comment: nope, not yet. Hopefully that scene will get some attention in Justice League itself!

Comment: Wait, is [your own answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/123558/21267) not sufficient?

Comment: @Möoz - lol i forgot i wrote that one. They're not exactly the same question (that one was trying to confirm that it was the Flash in the portal), but it's close enough I'll VTC as a duplicate. I could just delete it, but the questions are slightly different.